# cash register with infinite loop and change counter c

Tags: c, loops, break

I have every thing in the program done to my ability but i can not get it to tell me the proper amount of change it stays at 0 for all coin values.

also how would i break the infinite loop when the amount of items entered is 0,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    //variables used
    int penny = 0;
    int nickel = 0;
    int dime = 0;
    int quarter = 0;
    int items = 0.0;
    double paid= 0.0;
    double total = 0.0;
    double price =0.0;
    double change = 0.0;
    int counter =0;

    for (;;)
    {
        printf("Please enter the number of grocery items:");
        scanf("%d", &items);

        for (counter = 1; counter <= items; counter++)
        {
            printf("Please enter the price for item #%d:", counter);
            scanf("%f", &price);

            total += price;

        }

        printf("Please enter amount payed:");
        scanf("%f", &paid);

        change = paid - total;

        while (change > 0)
        {
            if (change >= .25)
            {
                change = change - .25;
                quarter = quarter + 1;
            }
            else if (change >= .1)
            {
                change = change - .1;
                dime = dime + 1;
            }
            else if (change >= .05)
            {
                change = change - .05;
                nickel = nickel + 1;
            }
            else if (change >= .01)
            {
                change = change - .01;
                penny = penny + 1;
            }
        }

        printf("this is your change %d quarters, %d dimes, %d nickels, %d pennies.\n", quarter, dime, nickel, penny);



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use floats instead of doubles.

Tp break out of the loop after checking if items == 0.

```
for (;;)  {
    printf("Please enter the number of grocery items:");
    scanf("%d", &items);

    if (items == 0) {
        break;
    }

    for (counter = 1; counter <= items; counter++) {
        printf("Please enter the price for item #%d:", counter);
        scanf("%f", &price);
        total += price;
    }
    etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `scanf()` specifier is wrong, use `"%lf"` from `double`
 or better, change all `double` variables to `float`.

Comment: That didn't change anything

Comment: @jparks54 I tested the program and it was fixed that way. Can you give a sample input? Of course, you are aware that your program will always output the change in `quarters`, aren't you?